# asp.net form postback or not depending on button clicked

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback

I need an idea for a situation like this:
There is this aspx form which contains some buttons like "save", "import", and print;
on the last one clicked a window should appear providing the user with a print-friendly version. what i need is the form not to cause postback and reload in this case, while normally postback-ing when the other buttons are clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use hyperlink with target="_blank" to open up the document in a new window.

If you like to use the button, you have to use the window.open syntax to open a new page: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

HTH.